# How to overcome the Window Selection limitation in the Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I just implemented a custom window selection 'https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-simpler-extension' in my Forge Application. But, I was confronted with its limitation; I mean that it detects objects that doesn't belong to my selection. After research, I found out that we select the bounding box of objects instead of the object boundaries.

Has anyone overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Forge viewer native window selection extension called `Autodesk.BoxSelection`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558151/7745569 for the usage instruction.